# GitHub API: Number of Stars of a Repository Over Time

Tags: github-api

Is there a way to retrieve information about the number of stars of a GitHub repository over time? I know I can get a list of all users who starred a repository using the `stargazers` API endpoint. This doesn't include information about when each user has starred the repo, though. Any hints on how I can retrieve this data?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the property `starred_at` using this custom media :

```
Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.star+json
```

Your headers might look something like this (I'm using Javascript here):

```js
headers: {
    ...
    Accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3.star+json',
    ...
},
```

See the documentation here: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#alternative-response-with-star-creation-timestamps

This repository: https://github.com/timqian/star-history uses this technique to retrieve the stars over time to create a chart.