# Using github api fetch number of stars overtime of a repository in python

Tags: python, python-requests, github-api

w.r.t to this post: [GitHub API: Number of Stars of a Repository Over Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61836313/github-api-number-of-stars-of-a-repository-over-time)
I'm trying to do the same in python, here is the code snippet:

```
import requests
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/flutter/flutter/stargazers?per_page=1"
repo_response = requests.get(url,headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'})
print(repo_response.json())
```

According to the [Git API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#starring), I've sent the accept in headers but I still fail to get the "*Alternative response with star creation timestamps*".
The result is that of a default response.

Is there something that I'm missing out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you forgot to add something in header (application/vnd.github.v3.**star**)

```
repo_response = requests.get(url,headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.star+json'})
```